# How many different words can be formed using the letters of the word " PERMUTACION"?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, permutations, combinations

Is there any guide to solve this?

Edit:

This is what I do. I used the permutations. Please check if I did the right thing?

Since 11 words so i did 11Pr

1 letter 11p1

2 letter 11p2   11

3 letter 11p3 990

4 letter 11p4 7920

5 letter 11p5 55440

6 letter 11p6 332640

7 letter 11p7 1663200

8 letter 11p8 6652800

9 letter 11p9 19958400

10 letter 11p10 399161800

11 letter 11p11 399161800

In short the answer is 108505111 ways

AM i right?

Comment: The hint is in the question. What do you know about permutations?

Comment: Words in which language? Any? Who decides what is a word?

Comment: @HenningMakholm I think how many words can be made if they scramble the word "permutacion". Idk my prof is so tricky and it give me only glimpse about this

Comment: Are "PUMAER" or "TUMOREN" words that should be counted, for example? They are perfectly good words in Danish, but not, as far as I'm aware, in English. No idea whether they count in Spanish. How about "TIMOR", a proper noun?

Comment: We should have more constraints on what is required.

Comment: @HenningMakholm kindly check my edit sir.  I used permutation

Comment: Define what a 'word' is first. Example: Is PEEE a word? or is P a word?

Comment: @EmmadKareem I think there's no exact meaning in english. It's like how many these words can be formed. How many times sort of that sir

Comment: @HenningMakholm Sir i think there's no really exact meaning in english. It's like how many words can be formed using this letter. Kindly check my edit part.

Comment: @Robert: Just repeating "how many words" again and again does not help you until you _define your terms_ and reveal to us what a "word" means to you in this context. If the terms used in your question "have no exact meaning", then your question **does not have an exact answer either**.

Comment: Maybe you can use this as a guide to re-formulate your question: How many (different/unique) permutations of (some/all/of min length x/of max length y) of the letters in the string "permutacion" (with at most/least n repetitions) allowed.

Comment: The implicit assumption from OP's work seems to be that all strings of letters are considered "words".

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you have not formulated the question, which is quite vague.

Making the assumption that it means permutations of letters of length 1 through 11 from PERMUTACION, your approach is correct.

I haven't checked the computations, except for noting the obvious oversights/errors in the very first two: You have not entered what $^{11}P_1$ equals, and $^{11}P_2$ is not 11

Comment: The computation is okay.  The answer is that there are 108505111 permutations of length 1 to 11, that can be selected without replacement.